# Creating a group without a folder in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, github, xcode9

Is there a way to convert an existing "Group" to a "Group without a folder" in Xcode 9?

I have projects where I include code from other a folder that's under a different git repository. This worked fine in previous versions of Xcode.

This is causing issues now in Xcode 9 where it's created folder references now to these groups. For instance, if I try to change the name of this group in Xcode I get the following error and it marks all the files as deleted in the other git repository.

```
“Group1” couldn’t be moved to “Group2” because an item with the same name already exists.
```

I'm confused how to best handle this in the new version of Xcode 9. Do I create a group without a folder and then drag the files individually instead of trying to create a group in Xcode by dragging the folder from Finder?

If more explanation is needed please let me know. It's a hard issue to explain and I don't quite understand why Apple made this change in Xcode. What's even more confusing is the context menu changes when you create a group in a group without a folder or a group with a folder.

Comment: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88260

Answer (score 0):

Your answer; phrased as a question seems fine:

> Do I create a group without a folder and then drag the files
>   individually instead of trying to create a group in Xcode by dragging
>   the folder from Finder?

Tested workflow

1. Create a group without folder
2. Drag the file(s) to the Xcode project
   and select option for copying the file.